# Как заставить генератор случайных чисел давать дробные значения?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Не могу понять как заставить генератор случайных чисел давать дробные значения.
Пробовал сделать так.
    `A = rand() % 158.691+(-1.235);`

не получилось.
Интервал от -1.235 и 157.456.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N,M;
    int max = 157456, min = -1235;
    cout << "Enter size of matrix A:N " << endl;
    cin >> M;
    cout << "Enter size of matrix A:M " << endl;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Creating matrix A:" << endl;
    // Создаётся матрица A
    float **A = new float* [M];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0;
    do {
        A[i] = new float [N];
        i++;
    }
    while(i<N);
    int j = 0;
    do {
        do {
            float float k = rand();
            k = k%(max - min) + min;
            //double результат = (double)число / (double)1000;
            A[i][j] = (float)k/(float)1000;;
            cout << setw(10) << A[i][j];
            i++;
        }
        while(i<M);
        j++;
        cout << endl;
    } 
    while(j<N);

    cout << endl << endl;

 // Освобождение памяти
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) delete [] A[i];
    delete [] A;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: float float?))

Comment: Ну товарищ @manking написал long long. Я подставил float float. А что?

Comment: ну хотя бы то, что long long есть, а float float - нет

Comment: Почему? что почитать чтобы было?

Comment: Вы меня спрашиваете почему? Спросите об этом у создателей языка. В частности, у г-на Страуструпа. 

>что почитать чтобы было?

я вам еще раз русским языком говорю - типа float float в C++ не существует

Comment: Ясно. При написании программы с функцией генерации случайных чисел, новичку приходится перелопачивать кучу всякой всячины лишь для генерации вещественных чисел с плавающей точкой... Я конечно понимаю что можно свой написать, а в библиотеку их сразу включить невозможно?

Comment: Для того чтобы делить по модулю число должно быть целое.
float дробное. 
Вы вначале разберитесь с локальной задачей получения случайного числа, а уже потом создавайте матрицу и всё остальное.

Замените ваш float float на int, long,long long. Или выберите что по душе из этого списка: 

http://cppstudio.com/uchebniki/yazyk-programmirovaniya-s/tipy-dannyx-s/

Comment: в какую библиотеку?

Comment: >Я конечно понимаю что можно свой написать, а в библиотеку их сразу включить невозможно?

@AQZ вы так обиженно говорите об этом, будто кто-то из здесь присутствующих является разработчиком стандатра этого языка. Для  совсем уж новичков есть языки попроще - C++ не для тех, кто ищет всё готовое, и  это вы еще споткнулись о то место, мимо которого многие проходят, не заметив. Дальше вашему удивлению не будет предела. 
Ну а перелопатить немного всякой всячины - это новичку не повредит, уж поверьте

Comment: @manking то есть дробные случайные числа никак не получить типа float? У меня просто задание: заполнить массив случайными числами из данного диапазона. Числа должны быть типа float. И циклом do while заполнять и выводить.

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ я ваш код исправил и сейчас выложу. Там элементарные ошибки, с переполнением буфера.

Comment: @AQZ, по возможности применяйте `double` вместо `float`. По крайней мере пока только начинаете писать программы.

Comment: @avp 
А в чём проблема с float? Слишком маленькое?

Comment: @manking, хотя бы в том, что float сейчас бессмысленен и более тормозной, чем double. Есть мнение, что современные процессоры нативно работают с double - в смысле у них регистры той же разрядности. Чай, проги не на 386 запускаться будут.

Comment: @gecube
Наверное да. Я помню в движке PhysX везде поголовно один double. То есть можно взять short, int но нет только double для всего и везде.

Когда говорят " производительность процессора: 1 000 000 операций, с плавающей точкой в секунду" подразумевается double?

Comment: @manking, float - да маленькое. И дело тут еще в неявных преобразованиях в передаче в параметрах и путанице с форматами ввода.

В общем, без особой нужда в экономии памяти (если точность позволяет) лучше везде использовать double. Конечно, не для замены целых (char, short, int, long ...).

--

Про производительность. Если без лукавства говорят, то обычно о double. Иногда уточняют. 

Дело в том, что у некоторых процессоров производительность с одинарной точкой (float) вдвое выше, чем с double. Но, обычно это для векторных команд (в граф картах, например).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На самом деле всё просто.

```
// Генерирует случайное действительное число от 0 до 1
(double)(rand())/RAND_MAX 
// Генерирует случайное действительное число от 0 до N
(double)(rand())/RAND_MAX * N
```

Вот пример:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Функция, генерирующая случайное действительное число от min до max
double random(double min, double max)
{
    return (double)(rand())/RAND_MAX*(max - min) + min;
}

int main() 
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    cout << random(-1.235, 157.456) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/229995/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9) проверка.

Comment: @Сергей Пестов,  только одно замечание.

В \*nix функция `random()` определена в `stdlib.h` (правда у нее другой прототип).

    
    /* These are the functions that actually do things.  The `random', `srandom',
    `initstate' and `setstate' functions are those from BSD Unices.
    The `rand' and `srand' functions are required by the ANSI standard.
    We provide both interfaces to the same random number generator.  */

Данный пример в С++ работать будет (а в Си не будет компилироваться), но все же лучше свои функции так не называть.

Comment: @VladD, Вы не учитываете того, что происходит деление, которое наверняка заполнит все биты мантиссы double.

Comment: @avp, Вы правы:
rnd.c:5:8: error: conflicting types for ‘random’
/usr/include/stdlib.h:327:17: note: previous declaration of ‘random’ was here

Comment: @Сергей Пестов: я немного не об этом. Биты-то будут заполнены, вопросов нет. Но если `int`, например, четырёхбитный, то и после деления вы получите не более чем 256^4 различных значений. Поскольку double длиной 8 байт, он может принимать около 256^8 различных значений (за вычетом 2^11 значений для бесконечностей и NaN). Видите проблему?

Comment: IMHO

    return ((double)rand() * rand())/RAND_MAX*(max - min) + min;

решает ее.

Конечно, тут наверное возникнут другие проблемы уже с качеством этих чисел.

Comment: Кроме этого я просто ошибся в формуле.

RAND_MAX надо бы в квадрат возвести.

--

Вообще-то тема псевдослучайных чисел достаточно сложная. Если нужны хорошие результаты, то ей серьезно надо заниматься.

Comment: @avp: Я думал над вашим примером. На самом деле неверно, и вот почему: произведение равномерно распределённых случайных величин не является _равномерно_ распределённой случайной величиной. (У Кнута был похожий случай в практике, описан в главе 3.1, Алгоритм К.)

Comment: @VladD, совершенно согласен. И это тоже я имел в виду, когда говорил о *качестве* этих (умножение 2-х rand()) чисел, а еще наверняка куча критериев "случайности" нарушается.

На самом деле серьезно я псевдослучайными числами не занимался, но Кнута когда-то читал и понял, что в этой области все не слишком интуитивно (как минимум там хорошая мат. подготовка (и наверное текущая форма тоже) нужна).

--

Может тогда лучше слепить uint64_t из 62 бит 2-х rand() (если они 32-х разрядные или 60 бит из 4-х 16-разрядных) и присвоить его double? Ну, пропадет часть из них (в мантиссе 52 бита) и ладно...

Comment: @avp: наверное, так будет лучше. Пусть лучше будут лишние биты, которые потеряются, чем риск плохого качества случайных чисел (с возможными проблемами криптографического характера). Хотя, конечно, если речь идёт о криптографии, лучше довериться специалистам-математикам.

Comment: Проверил генератор, как и следовало ожидать, работает так, как нужно: http://hashcode.ru/research/229995/c-проверка генератора случайных чисел с плавающей функцией

Comment: @Сергей Пестов: сомнения были не в `(double)(rand())/RAND_MAX`, а в `(double)(rand())*rand()/(RAND_MAX*RAND_MAX)`.

Answer (score 5):

Все вышеперечисленные способы сводятся примерно к одной формуле:

```
res = min + (max - min) / RAND_MAX * rand();
```

Тут могут быть проблемы, если число значащих цифр в `RAND_MAX` меньше, чем в мантиссе результирующего типа. Такое может случиться, даже если `res` имеет тип `float` (`RAND_MAX` далеко не всегда равен `INT_MAX`, а может быть намного меньше). Возможно, что и в противном случае, с распеределением что-то будет не так, не могу сказать точно.

---

Поэтому, не может не радовать, что разработчики стандарта позаботились о нас и добавили в стандартную библиотеку новый модуль <[random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)>.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
  const double from = -1.235;
  const double to = 157.456;
  using namespace std::chrono;
  std::default_random_engine engine(
      system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now()));
  std::uniform_real_distribution<> distr(from, to);
  auto gen_number = [&engine, &distr] () { return distr(engine); };
  for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    std::cout << gen_number() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Или, если без обилия лишних буковок, то

    #include <iostream>
    #include <random>
    #include <time.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
      double from = -1.235;
      double to = 157.456;
    
      default_random_engine engine(time(0));
      uniform_real_distribution<> myrandom(from, to);
    
      for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        cout << myrandom(engine) << endl;
    }

IMHO выглядит менее устрашающе.

Comment: @avp зато у вас смешивается сишная функция time с плюсами, что тоже не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 4):

Вот так работает?

```
double мин = -1.235;
double макс = 157.456;

int мин__ = (int)(мин*1000);
int макс__ = (int)(макс*1000);

long long число = rand(); 
число =  число%(макс__ - мин__) + мин__;
double результат = (double)число / (double)1000;
std::cout << "\nрезультат=" << результат;
```

Проверка:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
int min = -1235;
int max = 157456;
    //
srand(наносекунды);
long long D = rand(); 
D =  D%(max - min) + min;
double result = (double)D / (double)1000;

if(result < -1.235)
{
std::cout << "\nменьше=" << result;
}

if(result > 157.456)
{
std::cout << "\nбольше=" << result;
}

}
```

---

@
Вот ваш код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;




int main(){

    int N,M;
    int max = 157456, min = -1235;
    cout << "Enter size of matrix A:N " << endl;
    cin >> M;
    cout << "Enter size of matrix A:M " << endl;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Creating matrix A:" << endl;
    // Создаётся матрица A
    float **A = new float* [M];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0;
    do {
        A[i] = new float [N];
        i++;
    }
    while(i<M);
    int j = 0;

// Здесь обнулить счётчик i
i = 0;

    do {
        do {
            int k = rand();
            k = k%(max - min) + min;
            //double результат = (double)число / (double)1000;
            A[i][j] = (float)k/(float)1000;;
            cout << setw(10) << A[i][j];
            i++;
        }
        while(i<M);

// Здесь еще раз обнулить счётчик i
i=0;

        j++;
        cout << endl;
    } 
    while(j<N);

    cout << endl << endl;

 // Освобождение памяти
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i ++) delete [] A[i];
    delete [] A;
    system("pause");
}
```

// обновление семя раз в секунду
srand(секунды);

[image]

// обновление семя 1000 раз в секунду
srand(миллисекунды);
[image]

// обновление семя 1000000 раз в секунду
srand(микросекунды);

[image]

// обновление семя 1000000000 раз в секунду
srand(наносекунды);

[image]

Вид пикселей:

Секунды:

[image]

Миллисекунды:

[image]

Микросекунды:

[image]

Наносекунды:

[image]

Comment: Выдает такие ошибки преобразования типов:
1>c:\documents and settings\1\мои документы\visual studio 2010\projects\lab5\lab5.cpp(28): warning C4244: инициализация: преобразование "int" в "float", возможна потеря данных
1>c:\documents and settings\1\мои документы\visual studio 2010\projects\lab5\lab5.cpp(29): error C2296: %: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "float"

Comment: Warning убрал. 
А где у вас error C2296: %: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "float" 

Вы код скопировали или переписали? Покажите сам код.

Comment: Ошибка вышла после выполнения 
http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130617/rz5VGQUC.png

Comment: Ну, в условиях задания сказано что с помощью do .. while делать.
Можно конечно сказать преподу, что условие задачи неправильно поставлено.

При квадратном массиве все нормально. При разных значениях M и N происходит ошибка.

Comment: @AQZ 

Исправил снова.
У вас память выделяется на M, заполняете вы это на N. Удаляете на N.

Comment: Точно. Поэтому буду лучше читать про динамические массивы.

Answer (score 3):

```
srand(time(NULL));
double a = (double)(rand()%10000);
```

ну и соответственно добавьте слагаемые-множители для соблюдения требуемого диапазона

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен что с цифрами правильно высчитал, так что если подойдёт такое решение сами пере проверти, что бы он нужные вам числа выдавал.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    double result;
    int celoe = 0, drobi = 0, znak = 0;
    char buff[10];

    znak = rand() % 2; // 1

    buff[0] = znak ? ' ' : '-';

    if (buff[0] == '-') {  // 2
        celoe = rand() % 2; // Генерирует от 0 до 1
        drobi = rand() % 236; // Генерирует от 0 до 235
        sprintf(&buff[1], "%d.%d", celoe, drobi); // 4
    } else {  //3
        celoe = rand() % 158; // Генерирует от 0 до 157
        drobi = rand() % 457; // Генерирует от 0 до 456
        sprintf(buff, "%d.%d", celoe, drobi); // 4
    }

    result = atof(buff);  // 5

    std::cout << result << "\n";  // 6

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

1. Генерируем число от 0 до 1 которое будет определять знак будущего дробного числа.
2. Проверяем если у нас число будет отрицательным то генерируем значения из диапазона чисел которые могут входить в отрицательное дробное число.
3. Ну а если число положительное то для положительного генерируем числа из нужного вам диапазона.
4. Здесь мы создаём из получившихся чисел строку с дробным числом.
5. Преобразуем строку с числом в число double
6. Выводим результат

P.S. Народ если есть простой способ генерировать дробные значения то отпишитесь, может зря я такую муть городил на ночь глядя ))

А можно вынести в отдельную функцию и при вызове функции передавать нужные диапазоны и получать результат.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

double generate(int min_celoe, int min_drobi, int max_celoe, int max_drobi)
{
    double result;
    int celoe = 0, drobi = 0, znak = 0;
    char buff[10];

    znak = rand() % 2;

    buff[0] = znak ? ' ' : '-';

    if (buff[0] == '-') {
        celoe = rand() % (min_celoe + 1);
        drobi = rand() % (min_drobi + 1);
        sprintf(&buff[1], "%d.%d", celoe, drobi);
    } else {
        celoe = rand() % (max_celoe + 1);
        drobi = rand() % (max_drobi + 1);
        sprintf(buff, "%d.%d", celoe, drobi);
    }

    result = atof(buff);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    double results[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        results[i] = generate(1, 235, 157, 456);
        std::cout << results[i] << "\n";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: так а чем вам мой вариант не нравится?)

Comment: Вроде как мое решение ни каким образом не относится к вашему.
Вы просто генерируете случайное число от 0 до 9999.

Comment: Хорошая идея. Добротная. Попробую.